# World size limit in Box2D

Tags: box2d

In Box2D, I am aware that the world size is unlimited. However, I am producing an infinite scrolling game, and I am concerned that large coordinate values will slow calculations, and thus gamespeed.

Will large coordinate values slow it down? If so, is there a way to translate the coordinates of all bodies in the world, to keep them small? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Large coordinates will not slow anything down, but you will lose precision. The b2World class has a function called shift to help you with this.
https://code.google.com/p/box2d/source/browse/trunk/Box2D/Box2D/Dynamics/b2World.h#197